# Is it possible to draw vertical lines which have different lengths with css?

Tags: html, css

I can draw vertical lines in background using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764947/is-it-possible-to-draw-vertical-lines-via-css-gradients-starting-from-arbitrary).
And this answer draws same length of vertical lines.

But I'd like to draw the following lines. (5th line is a bit longer than others.)
[image]

Currently, I drew these lines with 1px width `divs`. But after checking the above answer, I am wondering if I can draw only via css. But still not sure if it's possible.

Looking forward to any advices. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One needs to keep in mind that CSS is not a drawing program or even a graphics program. While lines can be created in limited ways, it is often best to use SVG for such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easier idea using `repeating-linear-gradient`

```css
.line {
  height: 50px;
  background:
   repeating-linear-gradient(to right, red   0 4px, transparent 4px 80px),
   repeating-linear-gradient(to right, green 0 4px, transparent 4px 20px) left/100% 70% no-repeat;

}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Using CSS variables to easily control everything:

```css
div.line {
  --d:20px; /* distance between lines */
  --l:4px;  /* length of line */
  --n:4;    /* how many small lines between the big one*/
  --h:70%;  /* Height of small lines*/
  --o:0;    /* When the big line will start */

  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, 
      red   0 var(--l), transparent var(--l) calc((var(--l) + var(--d))*(var(--n) + 1))) left calc(var(--o)*((var(--l) + var(--d)))) center no-repeat,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, 
      green 0 var(--l), transparent var(--l) calc(var(--l) + var(--d))) left/100% var(--h) no-repeat;
      
  margin:10px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line" style="--n:10;--h:50%;--o:2"></div>
<div class="line" style="--n:2;--d:35px;--l:2px;--o:3"></div>
<div class="line" style="--n:8;--l:10px;--d:5px;--o:8;--h:90%;"></div>
```

[image: CSS vertical lines with different lengths and linear gradient]

Answer (score 2):

You can make background with same length, then using `before` or `after` to create a vertical line with height longer and put it in the middle of the background

```css
div {
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 10% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 4px, transparent 1px, transparent);
  background-position: -2px center;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 4px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @Hai Bui, thanks. Is it possible to show vertical lines only 10 lines with same intervals even if the div width is changed?

Comment: You want to make it not broken when resize?

Comment: @AllenHaley in case above is 9 lines and 1 line height longer in middle. You want to another case 10 lines have same height and interval when width change, right?

Comment: You're right. 9 lines and 5th line is longer than others. So that, there will be always 10 intervals.

Comment: @Hai Bui, I finally got an answer by updating your answer. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main_div
{
  position:absolute;
  width:90%;
  border:1px solid;
  height:50%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.div_one
{
  position:relative;
  width:1%;
  border:1px solid;
  height:50%;
  background-color:black;
}
.div_five
{
  position:relative;
  width:1%;
  border:1px solid;
  height:60%;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="div_one"></div>
  <div class="div_one"></div>
  <div class="div_one"></div>
  <div class="div_one"></div>
  <div class="div_five"></div>
  <div class="div_one"></div>
  <div class="div_one"></div>
  <div class="div_one"></div>
  <div class="div_one"></div>
  <div class="div_one"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already tried this. What I want is to do only with css. thanks.